# Change the regional and language setting of the windows

Tags: vb6, regional-settings

[image]

I want to change the regional and language setting of the windows from the vb 6.0. Is there any way to change the regional and language setting to the windows' default like in the picture.

Answer (score 2):

If there is it would be a bad idea.

These settings belong to the user, not your programs.

Comment: I know that but I want to change the setting to the default if another  program or virus change it.

Comment: If a virus changes it, you've got bigger problems than regional settings.

Comment: He wants to restore settings **and** remove all viruses!

Comment: Hmm, is this part of one of those "Janitor in a Disk" programs people think they can dash off in 2 weeks.  I "Pity da foo'" who downloads and runs these sorts of things.  How would your program know what to set?  There is no "default" because the machine's default is set during installation.  Oh well, shutting up now.

Answer (score 0):

I think it is acceptable to change the settings while the program is running then restore the settings to old values.  Or even ask the user for permission.  Some times, it's necessary to do that.